# How to create UITableViewCell with dynamically height change according to array coming from API

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, height, cell

Its array data for only one cell view, I need to set product_name and total_quantity on table view cell.sometime total_quantity can be 2 sometime it can be 10. Just give me some basic idea so I can move forward.

> [[{"total_quantity":"50","product_id":"13","product_name":"Prawns"},{"total_quantity":"13","product_id":"14","product_name":"Fish"},{"total_quantity":"57","product_id":"15","product_name":"Chicken
>   Breast"},{"total_quantity":"10","product_id":"16","product_name":"Beef"}],[{"total_quantity":"50","product_id":"13","product_name":"Prawns"},{"total_quantity":"13","product_id":"14","product_name":"Fish"},{"total_quantity":"57","product_id":"15","product_name":"Chicken
>   Breast"},{"total_quantity":"10","product_id":"16","product_name":"Beef"}]]

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKMF9.png)

Comment: i think you need to use multiple cell of same class

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this, if you want to change the height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let object = myArrayDataset[indexPath.row]
    //for example
    if object.numberOfItems > 10 {
        return 80.0
    }
    else {
        return 40.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

extension String {

```
func sizeWithGivenSize(_ size: CGSize,font: UIFont,paragraph: NSMutableParagraphStyle? = nil) -> CGSize {
    var attributes = [String:AnyObject]()
    attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = font
    if let p = paragraph {
        attributes[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] = p
    }
    attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = font
    return (self as NSString).boundingRect(with: size,
                                           options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin,.usesFontLeading],
                                           attributes: attributes,
                                           context: nil).size
}
```

Use this Method to get UILabel's Frame with different length string.
then to calculate Height form top to bottom.
for high performance, you'd better to do this at model.

For example:

```
func calculateFrame() -> Void {
    let width = UIComponentsConst.screenWidth
    var tmpFrame = ProjectDetailTeamCellLayout()

    var maxX: CGFloat = 0
    var maxY: CGFloat = tmpFrame.topSpace

    if let titleText = title {
        let titleSize = titleText.sizeWithGivenSize(MaxSize, font: ProjectDetailTeamCellLayout.titleFont, paragraph: nil)
        tmpFrame.titleLabelFrame = CGRect.init(x: 15, y: maxY, width: titleSize.width, height: titleSize.height)
        maxY = tmpFrame.titleLabelFrame!.maxY
        maxX = tmpFrame.titleLabelFrame!.maxX
    }

    if let nameText = nameTitle, !nameText.isEmpty {
        tmpFrame.grayLineFrame = CGRect(x: maxX + tmpFrame.itemSpace, y: tmpFrame.topSpace, width: 1, height: tmpFrame.titleLabelFrame?.height ?? 0)
        let nameSize = nameText.sizeWithGivenSize(MaxSize, font: ProjectDetailTeamCellLayout.nameLabelFont, paragraph: nil)
        let nameTmpFrame = CGRect(x: tmpFrame.grayLineFrame!.maxX + tmpFrame.itemSpace, y: tmpFrame.topSpace + (tmpFrame.titleLabelFrame?.height ?? nameSize.height ) / 2 - nameSize.height / 2, width: nameSize.width, height: nameSize.height)
        tmpFrame.nameLabelFrame = nameTmpFrame
        maxY = maxY > tmpFrame.nameLabelFrame!.maxY ? maxY : tmpFrame.nameLabelFrame!.maxY
    }

    if let subTitleText = subTitle, !subTitleText.isEmpty {
        let subTitleSize = subTitleText.sizeWithGivenSize(CGSize(width: width - 45, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), font: ProjectDetailTeamCellLayout.subTitleFont, paragraph: nil)
        tmpFrame.subTitleLabelFrame = CGRect(x: 15, y: maxY + tmpFrame.lineSpace, width: subTitleSize.width, height: subTitleSize.height)
        maxY = tmpFrame.subTitleLabelFrame!.maxY + 10
    }
    tmpFrame.height = maxY + 5
    self.frameInfo = tmpFrame
}
```

try ?